# problem installing R after updating to ubuntu 22:04

Tags: r

I spent whole day without success.I can't get to work. Here is the problem

```
sudo apt install r-base-core
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
r-base-core is already the newest version (4.2.1-2.2204.0).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 9 not to upgrade



R

Command 'R' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install r-base-core
```

Comment: You are not using the default software sources for R. In 22.04, the supplied version is 4.1.2. There may be an issue with the packages in the software sources you use. Another thing to check: show the output of `echo $PATH`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using conda to install R, using the conda-forge channel.

```
conda install -c conda-forge r-base
```

You can also specify the version you'd like to install by adding a `=` and specifying the version. You can search the available versions by

```
conda search r-base
```

Comment: Thank you. Tried as you suggested but can't run R. Not sure where it has installed R.

Comment: How are you trying to initialize R? Typing `R` in the terminal should run R. R is usually installed in the path when conda is used. The probable path should be `/home/*username*/anaconda3/bin/` or `anaconda3/envs/*envname*/bin/` if you created a separate environment to install R. If you need further help you can refer this guide: https://www.biostars.org/p/450316/

Comment: Yes, I am typing R in the terminal to run R. I have miniconda3 installed. I can't find where R is installed.

Comment: Looks like R is not installed in /usr/local/bin. When I copied R from /usr/lib/R/bin to /usr/local/bin it seems to be working

Comment: That's interesting, I've never had this issue although I installed R using the same method above in Ubuntu 22.04.